# Вопрос по парсингу на JS

Tags: javascript, json

Есть вопрос по парсингу на JS

Такие строки:

```
$.get('http://site.ru', function (data) {
```

```
$this._user = $(".Moyklass", data).text();
```

Т.е. скрипт ищет на странице и выводит все вхождения .Moyklass.
На сайте css классов с таким названием много.
Мне надо, чтобы дергал только второй по счету .Moyklass , а все остальные игнорил. Помогите плиз

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this._user = $(".Moyklass", data).eq(1).text();
                                   ^^^^^
```